# Why is my chainsaw stalling?

Tags: engine, chainsaw, oil

The last time I used my chainsaw, It kept stalling. I could not keep it running. I had just used a new batch of gasoline with two-stroke engine oil added. As this was the only difference from the previous times I've used the chain saw, I suspect that I either added two much or too little two-stroke engine oil. Which would cause my chain saw tall stall like this, too much two-stroke oil in the gasoline or two little?

Comment: "* As this was the only difference from the previous times*", how about outside temperature, humidity, etc? How much time had passed too?

Answer (score 1):

Look for the "H" & "L" carb adjustment screws. Get a small screwdriver that will fit those screws. Crank it up, keep it running with the trigger. Adjust the "L" screw one way or the other, in quarter turn incriments, until it idles how you want. Keep track of the turns, in case that doesn't work.

Wind it up again, H screw may need a little tweak to get back up to the rpms you're looking for. Again, count your turns.

If that doesn't work, you may just have dryrotted gaslines, leaking too much air into the jets. $30 fix at most shops.